# Django css not working unless add 'whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware' in Middleware

Tags: css, django

My static file  settings are:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')

# Extra places for collectstatic to find static files.
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
)
```

My base html's static are as follows:

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
 {% block title_tag %}<title>{% block title %}{% if page.title %}{{ page.title }}{% endif %}{% endblock %}</title>{% endblock %}

    <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="{%  static 'favicon.ico' %}"/>
    <link href="{% static 'site/css/jquery-ui.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="{% static 'site/css/bootstrap.min.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="{% static 'site/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Satisfy' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link href="{% static 'site/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="{% static 'site/css/mystyle.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">

      {% block head_extra %}
        {% endblock head_extra %}  

  </head>
```

This settings not work until I use 'whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware', in Middleware as:

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    ...................
]
```

Could anyone suggest me how css work without whitenoise in local server. For your information my static folder in my project root.

Answer (score 0):

You should load static files first in your html before the html tag using

```
{% load staticfiles %}
```

Comment: have you inspect using developer tools to make sure the path of your css file is correct? @djpro. And you've to load the `{% load staticfiles %}` in your template file that extend the base html file.